# Pandas DataFrame.apply() and mibian

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mibian

I'm attempting to use a pandas dataframe that contains different pieces of options data to calculate implied volatility.  For the implied volatility I'm using [mibian](http://code.mibian.net/). Here's the code:

```
optionsData.to_dict():

    {'callclose': {0: Decimal('4'),
      1: Decimal('2.62'),
      2: Decimal('2.64'),
      3: Decimal('1.7'),
      4: Decimal('1.35')},
     'daystoexpiration': {0: 43L, 1: 43L, 2: 43L, 3: 43L, 4: 43L},
     'expiration': {0: datetime.date(2013, 2, 16),
      1: datetime.date(2013, 2, 16),
      2: datetime.date(2013, 2, 16),
      3: datetime.date(2013, 2, 16),
      4: datetime.date(2013, 2, 16)},
     'impvol': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
     'putclose': {0: Decimal('0.54'),
      1: Decimal('0.65'),
      2: Decimal('0.76'),
      3: Decimal('1.08'),
      4: Decimal('1.56')},
     'strike': {0: Decimal('39'),
      1: Decimal('40'),
      2: Decimal('41'),
      3: Decimal('42'),
      4: Decimal('43')},
     'symbol': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'A', 4: 'A'},
     'underlyingclose': {0: Decimal('42.86'),
      1: Decimal('42.86'),
      2: Decimal('42.86'),
      3: Decimal('42.86'),
      4: Decimal('42.86')}}

optionsData = optionsData.T

def calcvol(info):
    print info.name
    print 'Starting procedure.'
    tempmb = mb.BS([info['underlyingclose'], 
            info['strike'], 
            .25, 
            info['daystoexpiration']],
           callPrice=float(info['callclose']), 
           putPrice=info['putclose'])
    print 'mb created'
    impvol = tempmb.impliedVolatility
    print 'implied vol calculated'
    info['impvol'] = impvol
    print 'impvol set'
    del impvol, tempmb
    print 'vars deleted'
    return info

a = optionsData.apply(calcvol)
```

When I run through all of that, it sets the impvol on the first element in optionsData, but seems to subsequently give me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-116f3c010b9c> in <module>()
----> 1 a = optionsData.apply(calcvol)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\frame.pyc in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, args, **kwds)
   4079                     return self._apply_raw(f, axis)
   4080                 else:
-> 4081                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis)
   4082             else:
   4083                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures)
   4154                     # no k defined yet
   4155                     pass
-> 4156                 raise e
   4157 
   4158         if len(results) > 0 and _is_sequence(results[0]):

ZeroDivisionError: ('float division by zero', u'occurred at index 1')

0
Starting procedure.
mb created
implied vol calculated
impvol set
vars deleted
0
Starting procedure.
mb created
implied vol calculated
impvol set
vars deleted
1
Starting procedure.
```

I've got to be missing something simple.  I've tried wrapping each of the values in float() as I pass them to mibian, and still get the same issue.  I'd very much appreciate any guidance.

Also, if you know of a more efficient way to calculate implied volatility using a dataframe, I'm all ears.

Comment: Have you tested the `calcvol` function separately? It's good practice to do that first before you apply. (I don't suppose this is a simple as a forgotten axis argument: `optionsData.apply(calcvol, axis=1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As hayden commented, I did try the function separately, but not on a large enough sample size.

Apparently for some values of those variables, it will approximate to zero.  I changed my `calcvol` function to try using mibian to get the volatility, and if a `ZeroDivisionError` is caught then set `impvol` to `NaN`.  That'll help me figure out which ones are causing such a ruckus.

Comment: Catching the error is a interesting way to debug +1, I wouldn't have thought of that!